# How to find wheather a value is already available in a textbox or not using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

Let us consider i am having a text box where i can enter user names separated by commas.

**EDIT: In Detail:**

1. I am having a text box and a search_button nearby.
2. When i click on the search box list of users will be displayed there in a popup with a check box nearby
3. When the user the clicks the check box and clicks submit the corresponding users name will be displayed on the text box.
4. My problem is: **I should not able to add the user name twice. That is when i click on the same user which i added already, it should throw an alert message and that corresponding name should not be  added in the text box.**

My code for this is given below:

```
  var res_user = '';
  // checked username will get
  var existing_names = $('#text_box').val();
  $('#popups input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    res_user = res_user + $(this).parent().next().attr('value') + ', ';
  });
  if ($("#text_box").length > 0) {
    target = $("#text_box").val($("#text_box").val() + ' ' + res_user);
  }      
  Drupal.popups.close();
  return false;
```

How can this be **done using Jquery.**

Any help will be thankful and grateful....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In order to know what implementation options would be to your satisfaction, we need to know when you want to check the value of the field?  When the field loses focus?  When the user pauses typing for some number of seconds?  On every keystroke?  After copy/paste?  After drag/drop?

Comment: @@jfriend00: Hope now it's clear. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow how your UI works.  I guess it's a textbox that the user doesn't type in and the names come from somewhere else.  But, if the names only come from a pick list, then it sounds like you just need to do a regex search of the textbox before adding a name to make sure it's not already there.  Including the relevant part of your HTML might help us understand how the UI works.  Right now, I don't know what edit-assign-recipient or edit-mails are.

Comment: 1.edit-assign-recipient is the text box name 2. just ignore edit-mails. kindly tell me how to do the regex part using jquery for above scenario. Else how can i compare the variables existing names and rec_user. Both the variable are comma separated. Example existing_names = username1, username2, username3. rec_user = username4, username5, username1. How do i compare this case using jqyery. Thanks for helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.  It puts all the newly selected users into an array.  Then, it loops through that array, makes a regular expression out of each name and looks for that regex in the comma separated list.  If it's found, then we don't add this one.  If it's not found, we add it.

```
var selectedUsers = [];
// checked username will get added to selectedUsers array
$('#popups input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    selectedUsers.push($(this).parent().next().attr('value'));
});

var currentUsers = $("#text_box").val();
var regex;
for (var i = 0; i < selectedUsers.length; i++) {
    // make regex for this selectedUser so we can search to see if it's already there
    regex = new RegExp("(^|, )" + selectedUsers[i] + "(,|$)", "i"); 
    // if this username not found in the current string, then we can add it
    if (currentUsers.search(regex) == -1) {
         if (currentUsers.length != 0) {
             currentUsers += ", ";
         }
         currentUsers += selectedUsers[i];
    }
}
// put updated user list back in the textbox
$("#text_box").val(currentUsers);
```

You can see a slightly modified version with my own HTML work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/du6UF/.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function in your script tag:

```
$(function(){

$('#TextBox').change(function() {

    var $current = $(this);

        if ($(this).val() == $current.val()
        {
            alert('duplicate found!');
        }

  });
});
```

Comment: did you copied and pasted it as it is? or you tried it tweaking according to your html and requirement?

Comment: Kindly view the edited question. How can i compare the variables existing names and rec_user. Both the variable are comma separated. Example existing_names = username1, username2, username3. rec_user = username4, username5, username1.